# Split String in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, string

I need to split one string in multiple parts. The string is a set of unique usernames, but i retrieve the three names all together with spaces between. I need to put some ' between the end of one and the beginning of another so i can use them for MySQL Query purposes.

I already use arrays, but this time is different, because this field is filled with data from database.

If the users are added/removed, it will use the array, but if not, it will use this string that i want to format.

I have this code at the moment:

```
$Pessoas2=  implode(" ", $_POST['Pessoas']);
 $Pessoas2 = str_replace(';', ' ' , $Pessoas2);

(...)

$to = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Email FROM utilizadores WHERE Nome IN ( $Pessoas2)");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($to)){ 
    echo $row['Email'];
    echo ";";

 foreach ($row as $destino);

 echo $destino;
```

Comment: Example input and output?

Comment: At the moment the output of $Pessoas2 is Tiago Sara Luis Carlos

Comment: and how do you want it to be ?

Comment: and the input in `$_POST['Pessoas']` ?

Comment: Also please be aware you are wide open to SQL injection with your current code.

Comment: 'Tiago' 'Sara' 'Luis' 'Carlos'  so i can use them for querying.

Comment: $Pessoas2=  implode("','", $_POST['Pessoas']);$Pessoas2 = "'$Pessoas2'";

Comment: @edmondscommerce, how can i protect myself then?

Comment: I will do a proper answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure from your question if `$_POST['Pessoas']` is a string with usernames separated by space or if it's an array.

If it's a string separated by spaces, then try:

```
$Pessoas2 = "'" . preg_replace('/ /', "','", $_POST['Pessoas'])) . "'";
```

If it's an array, then try:

```
$Pessoas2 = "'" . implode("','", $_POST['Pessoas'])) . "'";
```

And then use `$Pessoas2` in your query just as you had it written.

Comment: @Alvin Lee, i'm getting 'Tiago;','Sara;','Luis'

Comment: Solved. Used this  $Pessoas2 = "'" . preg_replace('/; /', "','", $_POST['Pessoas']) . "'";

Comment: @Luís Assunção - glad that it worked out for you. Welcome to StackOverflow. Just as a suggestion: in the future, if you provide more information when writing your question (for example: an example of what the value of `$_POST['Pessoas']` might be), then you are likely to get quicker and more helpful answers to your questions. Happy programming!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code :

```
$Pessoas2 =  implode("','", $_POST['Pessoas']);
$Pessoas2 =  "'".$Pessoas2."'";
```

instead of

```
$Pessoas2=  implode(" ", $_POST['Pessoas']);
$Pessoas2 = str_replace(';', ' ' , $Pessoas2);
```

Comment: Remove these lines `$Pessoas2=  implode(" ", $_POST['Pessoas']);`
 `$Pessoas2 = str_replace(';', ' ' , $Pessoas2);`

Answer (score 0):

Couple things to address in your code. Ill answer your question, but also point out some problems.

```
//always escape values before db insertion - see real_escape_string here
$Pessoas2= mysqli_real_escape_string(implode("", $_POST['Pessoas']));
//using substr here to get rid of the trailing ','
//this is assuming the last name in the array has a trailing semicolon, don't use it otherwise.
$Pessoas2 = substr(str_replace(';', "','", $Pessoas2), 0, -3);

$to = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Email 
                         FROM utilizadores 
                        WHERE Nome IN ('". $Pessoas2 ."')");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($to)){ 
    echo $row['Email'];
    echo ";";
   //the semicolon does not belong after the foreach here.
   foreach ($row as $destino)
        echo $destino;
}
```

That should do what you want and help prevent sql injection.

Comment: echo $destino; It must show me the emails of the users. I don't have any error.

Comment: try to echo the query out and run it in phpmyadmin and make sure its actually doing what you think it should be. Does the last name in the array have a trailing ; ?

Comment: You're welcome, but you should still consider escaping the values before using them to query the database, could be a huge problem otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

A chance to use functional methodology! haha

```
$Pessoas2 = array_map( function($val) {
    return "'{$val}'";
}, explode(' ', $_POST['Pessoas']));

$sql = "SELECT Email FROM utilizadores WHERE Nome IN (".implode(',', $Pessoas2).")";
```

Comment: Are u sure u don't have any error on the first 3 lines?

Comment: well it will only work in PHP 5.3 or above, which you really should be using since PHP 5.2 is deprecated

Comment: fixed a typo in the explode part o.o

Comment: and another in the implode... i keep forgetting to close them brackets

Comment: ... and I switched `implode` and `explode` around. Thanks for the commentless downvote and/or downvoting because I didn't respond immediately

Comment: I didn't downvote ur answer. I can see that someone downvoted, but it wasn't me.